# question on Complex - Logarithmic Branch

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

$ \log(i^2) =2\log i$ when $\log z =\ln r +i\theta $ $(r>0, \pi/ 4
<\theta<
9\pi/ 4 )$

$\log(i^2) \neq 2\log i$ when $\log z =\ln r +i\theta $ $(r>0, 3\pi/ 4
<\theta<
11\pi/ 4 )$

My Try : Two of them are same. As both intervals contain $\pi$. so the value should be $\ln1 +i \pi$. Am I right? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that two of them are the same?

Comment: In two different intervals the value of $log(i^2)$ same..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both intervals $\left(\frac\pi4,\frac{9\pi}4\right)$ and $\left(\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{11\pi}4\right)$ contain $\pi$. But the first one contains $\frac\pi2$, whereas the second one doesn't. So, in the second case you can't even say what $\log i$ *is*. So what? There is no contradiction here. Don't forget that every non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms.

Comment: so what  would be the values in two different intervals@Jose Carlos Sanos

Comment: @cmi I have no idea about what you mean by this.

Comment: when theta belongs to $\left(\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{11\pi}4\right)$  then what would be the value?

Comment: @cmi Since $i^2=-1=1\times\bigl(\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)\bigr)$, $\log(i^2)=\ln1+i\pi=i\pi$. But I can say nothing about $\log i$, since $i$ cannot be written as $r\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)$ for some $\theta$ in your interval.